# Matlab - Subplot of 7 by 5 Scatterplots?

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, subplot

How can I create a subplot of say 7 x 5 scatterplots that include all, the points, and both histograms in Matlab?

[image]

For instance, if you try this code, you'll see that it doesn't work:

```
x = randn(1,1000); 
y = randn(1,1000); 
subplot(2,2,1); 
scatterhist(x,y)
```

I tried the following code from a previous post:

```
close all
h1 = figure
scatterhist(x,y)
h2 = figure
scatterhist(x,y)

h3 = figure
u1 = uipanel('position',[0,0,0.5,1]);
u2 = uipanel('position',[0.5,0,0.5,1]);

set(get(h1,'Children'),'parent',u1);
set(get(h2,'Children'),'parent',u2);

close(h1,h2)
```

...and this is the output:

[image]

I just ran KevinMc code and this is what it looks like:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want a figure with 7 times what you show in the picture ? Did you generate that yourself ?

Comment: Please clarify the question - Do you want 7x5 times the 3 plots generated in the picture?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I need. A subplot matrix with 7x5 plots

Comment: No duplication, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is wrong with the last picture you display ? Is it just that it doesn't have as many panels as you want ?

Comment: No no. I just need to know how to plot in the same format as subplot, not with subpanels... those are two stacked figures

Comment: What do you mean by "stacked figures"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have scatterhist, but here's something that works with scatter

```
nCols = 7;
nRows = 5;

mainfig = figure;
for currRow = 1:nRows
    for currCol = 1:nCols
        h = figure;
        scatter(rand(100, 1), randn(100, 1));
        figure(mainfig);
        u(currRow, currCol) = uipanel('Position', [(currCol-1)/nCols, (currRow-1)/nRows, 1/nCols, 1/nRows]);
        set(get(h, 'Children'), 'parent', u(currRow, currCol));
        close(h);
    end
end
```

The individual uipanels are stored in the array of handles `u`.

Comment: Hi KevinMc, thanks very much. That looks like what I need, but I still want to include the histograms... :( BTW I posted the figure from the code you provided

Comment: Just replace scatter with scatterhist in the code provided.  As I noted in the answer, I don't have the package containing scatterhist, so I used scatter instead.